# How to tell jQtouch to use a different div for the current div?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jqtouch

I am using jQtouch in a rails application and I have a page that is used for multiple actions(using multiple divs to speed things up).  I would like to be able to redirect to this page and based some "some" input, tell jQtouch to use that anchor instead of the one marked "current".  I have tried passing it the div I want chosen as an anchor but it seems to override this?  Can anyone provide any insight?

This is the html I'm trying to manipulate.  Typically I want to go to the checkin_item_checkin by default.

```
<div id="checkin_item_checkin" class="current">
  <div class="toolbar">  
   <a href="#" class="back">Back</a>
   <h1>Item CheckOut</h1>  
  </div>  
 <div id="info">
 </div> 
</div>

<div id="person_checkin">
  <div class="toolbar">  
    <a href="#" class="back">Back</a>
    <h1>Person Checkin</h1>  
  </div>  
</div>
```

Here is the rails code that I am using(though it could any language, this is a jQtouch question mainly).  Based on the decision in the controller, I want it to go to a different div on the same page.

```
def person_checkin
  unless params[:passport]
    flash[:notice] = "You must provide a passport to check a player in!"
    redirect_to checkin_home_url
  end

  @player = Person.find_by_passport(:passport=>params[:passport])
  if @player.eligible
    redirect_to checkin_home_url(:anchor=>"person_checkin")
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Player not eligible"
     redirect_to checkin_home_url
  end
  authorize! :checkin_player, Game
end
```